# Parallel task using Promise in Swift

Tags: swift, promise

I'm a bit confuse about the difference between `Promises.zip` and `Promises.all` in [this Promise Library](https://github.com/khanlou/Promise/blob/master/README.md)

Which one should I use if I want to execute 2 task in parallel and then use both their result for another task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at implementation of `Promises.all` and `Promises.zip` you see, that `.all` can work with `Promise`s with same type:

```
public static func all<T>(_ promises: [Promise<T>]) -> Promise<[T]>
```

But `.zip` can work with different types:

```
public static func zip<T, U>(_ first: Promise<T>, _ second: Promise<U>) -> Promise<(T, U)>
```

This is basic difference between these two.

P.S. Also, if you try to search in github by `zip` keyword, you can find this [issue](https://github.com/khanlou/Promise/issues/14), that helps you to understand the situation. So, always search first ;)

Comment: Both are parallel? Or sequential?

Comment: @Jaythaking, yes, "parallel" (async, actually). If you need sequential one - use chain feature of promises (`then`).